# I cant delete my project from visualstudio.com (TFS)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, azure-devops

I can not find where I delete my project when I log into my tfs at visualstudio.com, does anyone know?

It's unfortunate, but my project was created with VS2012. I tried the TFSDeleteProject in my VS2010 folder structure but it is complaining that it cant since its not the same version.

So where is that nifty deletebutton on the web?

Comment: Can you exactly specify command and also share what its complaining?

Comment: there is no command. How can i from the website, xxx.visualstudio.com delete my projects?

Comment: Did you check this? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/09/19/how-to-delete-a-team-project-from-tfs-on-azure.aspx

Comment: This gives me: TF200040: You cannot delete a team project with your version of Team Explorer. Contact your system administrator to determine how to upgrade your Team Explorer client to the version compatible with Team Foundation Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are using VS 2010 command prompt as mentioned at [Buck Hodges blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/09/19/how-to-delete-a-team-project-from-tfs-on-azure.aspx).

Either install VS 2012 or Team Explorer 2012